# Gradle - How to set dependency tasks for Exec-type tasks?

Tags: gradle

Say, you have following task:

```
task commandA() {
  doLast {
    project.ext.ping = 'PING'
  }   
}
```

This will work:

```
task commandB() {
    dependsOn commandA
    doLast {
        println ping
    }   
}
```

This will fail:

```
task commandC(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn commandA
    commandLine "echo", ping
}
```

With `Could not find property 'ping' on task 'commandC'.` error message.

So, how one can declare dependency for an exec-type task and set some variable in that dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't initialize the variable within the `doLast` block, since it's getting initialized at the execution phase, but `commandLine "echo", ping` is trying to get it at the configuration phase of the build.

So, you need something like that:

```
task commandA() {
    project.ext.ping = 'PING'     
}
```

Or even without task, as follows:

```
project.ext.ping = 'PING'
```

Because configuration of any task is always executed, even if the task's action won't be executed.

Another solution is to use exec-action, not exec-task, something like this:

```
task commandA() {
    doLast {
        project.ext.ping = 'PING'
    }
}

task commandC {
    dependsOn commandA
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine ping, "192.168.100.1"
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, exec-closure will be done during execution phase wuth the ping variable already available.

You can read about build lifecycle in the official Gradle [user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html)